# Android: load items on listview from a certain point onward

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have an activity that load messages from internet. Im downloading this to Sqlite, later add this to adapter.

I want to add on screen from a particular number onwards.
We may think we have added 100 items in arrayList adapter. and just we want to show from 75 onwards. SQLite I can add from the last 25, but can not do so because the adapter arrayList must contain all.
I've overwritten getCount () and return 25 to limit the maximum of items, but it does show the first 25 items,  not last 25 items.
I think I must do something in getView(). (method override in adapter)
Any ideas?

*************EDIT.ADD SOLUTION

adapter

```
  @Override
public int getCount() {
    if(messagesItems.size() <= maxRowsShow){
        return messagesItems.size();
    }else{
       offset = messagesItems.size() - maxRowsShow;
        return maxRowsShow;
    }

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        position = position + offset;
       ...}
```

Comment: You want to show in total 25 items in ListView start from 75 - 99, but the adapter should contain all of the data items. Is this what you want? Also just to clarify, is there any specific reason why Adapter should contain all the items?

Comment: Yes, you've understood.I have to do so for different reasons

Comment: manipulate the position number while fetching from datalist...post your adapter here

Comment: You may make an example?

Comment: Edit my question. Adding adapter code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you do the following.

1. Get offset of list from where you would like to show list. For eg. 75 from list of 100.
2. Return `offset - list.size()` in 'getCount()' of `Adapter`.
3. In `getView()` to get particular item do `item = list.get(offset + position)`

Comment: Oh ! Thanks for the solution! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but maybe you can load all the items in the adapter and then based on their position you can display the one's you need.

I am not sure if this is going to work but atleast you can give it a try.

Thanks